# NodeJS: How/where to keep a private credentials JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-cloud-storage, loopbackjs

I'm implementing bucket storage with Google Cloud Storage using [Loopback v3 storage component](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html). From the documentation, I need to provide the path to the service account credentials JSON file.

The JSON contains private keys and auth information, where/how can I store the JSON file securely and still being able to be accessed by the datasources?

Is there a solution/best-practice for this similar to storing as environment variables?

datasource:

```
"googleCloudStorage": {
    "name": "googleCloudStorage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "google",
    "keyFilename": "pathToCredentials.json",
    "projectId": "test-project",
    "nameConflict": "makeUnique"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not mandatory to have a `json` file for managing datasources in loopback. One can use a `.js` file. Environment varaibles can be easily read from this javascript code. Please check official documentation at https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html

Comment: I have tried changing it to `credentials.js` using `module.exports` and it's giving me error parsing JSON. Also tried exporting a stringified version and tried exporting this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(string))`

Comment: I think you will have to stick to loopback's way of naming files. Instead of `credentials.js` try `datasources.development.js`once.

Comment: yeah I have the datasources already in .js, how should I go with the json path in `keyFilename`? Ref: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html#provider-credentials